# What does this sentence imply? Past Simple

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-constructions

"I learned English 2 years ago". What does it imply? Like a fact: I did learning at some time 2 years ago or I finished learning English 2 years ago? As far as I know it means the first option?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning has less to do with the verb tense and more with the definition of "learn." To "study" a thing is simply to spend time learning about it, but to "learn" a thing usually means to fully complete your learning of it. "I learned to juggle" means I acquired a skill that I now have. By contrast, "I'm learning to juggle" means that my study is still going on; I'm *working on* finishing my learning.

So yes, "I learned English 2 years ago" would tend to mean "I fully learned English, to a degree that could be considered finished, 2 years ago." If you mean "I did some learning," you could say "I *studied* English 2 years ago."